# angular 14 default router with param

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I created an angular app with the last version, i updated the base href to `/popup` to have the url `http://localhost:4200/popup`

i want, when the application opens in the url `http://localhost:4200/popup`, it redirects me to a 404 page, but when i add a param in the url `http://localhost:4200/popup/444444444` is opens a specific page.

I tried with the below code but i have this error:

> main.ts:13 Error: NG04014: Invalid configuration of route
> '/:requestNumber': path cannot start with a slash

```
<base href="/popup" />

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/:requestNumber', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: '/:requestNumber',
    component: AppComponent,
    resolve: { payment: PaymentResolverService },
  },
];
```

I added the resolver to check if the url has a param requestNumber or not.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't clear. If I understood you right - you can't expect a route with `/popup/444444` to be caught by an empty path (because it is not an empty path, because it has 44444 in it), therefore, you can't write this:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/:requestNumber', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

The path configuration above picks up **empty paths**, i.e. `/popup/`, when you want it to redirect to `/popup/:requestNumber`, where will it get the request number from?? (remember, the path that got you here was `/popup/`)

You can write this though, where empty paths are redirected to a 404 page:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: Some404Page,
    },
    {
        path: ':requestNumber',
        redirectTo: 'popup/:requestNumber',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'popup/:requestNumber',
        component: AppComponent,
        resolve: { payment: PaymentResolverService },
    },
];
```

Comment: i tired this but it not working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gwlkn3

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the only hit on Google, I'll just add a side-answer.

I was getting this error for apparently this route:

```
{
    path: 'stuff/moduleA',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/module-a/module-a.module').then(m => m.module-a)
},
```

Which didn't make sense since there's clearly no leading slash there. The problem was actually that this lazily loaded module contained a route that looked like this:

```
{
    path: '/',
    component: AComponent,
},
```

The fix was to change *this* `path` by changing it to `path: ''`.

So check the routes inside of the loaded module, even if that route isn't mentioned in the error.